# Get Country Code (Telephone) Using Locale In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to get **Country Code (telephone)** 
Below code is giving me RegionCode **"IN"** But I want to return **"+91"** Anyone knows How I will get?

```
let locale = Locale.current
print("locale.regionCode",locale.regionCode!)
```

I am Looking for **Apple Library**.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik  I am Looking for **Apple Library** Without using 3rd party library

Comment: The accepted answer to the question @Anbu.karhik linked to uses Core Telephony, which _is_ an Apple framework...

Comment: @CharlesSrstka

**I am Using This code :::**
`let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
        
        if let carrier = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider {
            
            print("carrier::",carrier)
            print("country code is: " + carrier.mobileCountryCode!);
            print("ISO country code is: " + carrier.isoCountryCode!);
        }`

Output:

`carrier:: CTCarrier (0x1c0240450) {
 Carrier name: [Carrier]
 Mobile Country Code: [404]
 Mobile Network Code:[44]
 ISO Country Code:[in]
 Allows VOIP? [YES]
}

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I am not Getting the correct Country code.